# #1064 - SQL syntax ERROR, how to solve it?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables[table_a, table_b, dataz] in a my database, when I create a `TRIGGER` as follow,

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigz AFTER INSERT ON table_a
FOR EACH ROW
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_b WHERE table_b.uid = '123') THEN
        INSERT INTO dataz
            VALUES('123');
```

Getting `ERROR` as,

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

I don't understand what I am missing here...

I am using `WAMP Server 2.4`, anybody have solution ?

---

**EDIT 1(for Nigel Ren)::**

SQL :

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigz AFTER INSERT ON table_a FOR EACH ROW 
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_b WHERE table_b.uid = 1) THEN
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dataz(userid) VALUES('123');
    END;
END IF;
```

ERROR :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

Comment: Can you please provide the table structure ?

Comment: So much doesn't look good . . . no `DELIMITER`, `BEGIN`, `END IF` . . .

Comment: @GordonLinoff when I remove `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_b WHERE table_b.uid = '123') THEN` this part, it's working fine

Comment: @GordonLinoff help me, Where I need to add `BEGIN` and `END`

Comment: you at least need an 'end if' where the end is at the moment.

Comment: @NigelRen I tried that also, getting error as `...right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 5`

Comment: @NigelRen check Edit 1 in question